# Como posicionar el elemento hijo al pie del padre

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como o porque utilizando margin-bottom: auto; al segundo elemento el tercero se pone al pie del elemento padre?. Estoy utilizando el margin-bottom: auto; pero no se me posiciona al pie del elemento padre como en el elemento de bootstrap. Alguien sabe porque no me funciona como en el ejemplo.

ester es el codigo

```
    <body>
<section class="sidebar">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3 mt-3 dashboard-text">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-clipboard-data" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M4 11a1 1 0 1 1 2 0v1a1 1 0 1 1-2 0v-1zm6-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0v5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V7zM7 9a1 1 0 0 1 2 0v3a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V9z"/>
                <path d="M4 1.5H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2V14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3.5a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1v-1z"/>
                <path d="M9.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3zm-3-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 6.5 4h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3z"/>
            </svg>
            <h1 class="ps-2">SICOT</h1>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr" style="color: white;">
        <div class="menu-sidebar p-3 mb-auto">
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-decoration-none">
                <a class="text-decoration-none d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center menu-item"href="#"><li class="">item1</li></a>
                <a class="text-decoration-none d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center menu-item"href="#"><li class="">item2</li></a>
                <a class="text-decoration-none d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center menu-item"href="#"><li class="">item3</li></a>
                <a class="text-decoration-none d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center menu-item"href="#"><li class="">item4</li></a>
                <a class="text-decoration-none d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center menu-item"href="#"><li class="">item5</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3 menu-item">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h8a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 2h8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 3.5v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2z"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.146 8.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L1.707 7.5H10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H1.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3z"/>
            </svg>
            <a href="/controller/logout.php">
                <h4>Salir</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
</section>
```

el ultimo div es el necesito tenerlo al pie del elemento padre

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones sin y con Bootstrap.
Siguiendo el código que pones en la pregunta:
**Sin bootstrap** pon a section las propiedades display: flex, flex-direction: column
**Con Bootstrap**: añade a section las clases d-flex flex-column
Ambas hacen lo mismo, pero si estás usnaod Bootstrap por coherencia lo haría con Bootstrap.